# Ruby block as an array element for splatting in public_send

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proc, ruby-block

I am trying to build a generic method using meta programming where it uses manipulating `method`s from `array` and `send` to the object using `splat`, following is the working snippet:

```
ALLOWED_DATA_TYPES = {
  'Integer' => [['to_i']],
  'Csv' => [['split', ',']]
}

ALLOWED_DATA_TYPES.each do |type, methods|
  define_method("#{type.downcase}_ified_value") do
    manipulated_value = value
    methods.each { |method| manipulated_value = manipulated_value.public_send(*method) }
    return manipulated_value
  end
end
```

It was working great so far, until we decided to add another datatype and it needs to call method on `array`, for e.g.

```
"1,2,3".split(',').map(&:to_f)
```

Now I am stuck, because it's a block. Technically, following code is working alright:

```
"1,2,3".public_send('split', ',').public_send(:map, &:to_f)
# => [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

But adding that `block` to array is throwing error

```
[['split', ','], ['map', &:to_f]]
# => SyntaxError: syntax error, unexpected &, expecting ']'
```

I know I can create a `proc` and call it with amp `&` but I hope u get it that it is loosing consistency, I need something that will just work with `splat` operator as defined using `#define_method`

I am out of ideas now, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of luck, `&` is not an operator - it is a special syntax that is only allowed in function parameters (both definition and invocation). One way you could do it is to reserve the last element of the array for the block; but then you always have to use it (even if it is just `nil`).

```
methods.each { |*method, proc| manipulated_value = manipulated_value.public_send(*method, &proc) }
```

This should work with `[['split', ',', nil], ['map', :to_f]]`.

Off-topic, but note that these three lines can be more succintly rewritten using `inject`:

```
manipulated_value = value
methods.each { |*method, proc| manipulated_value = manipulated_value.public_send(*method, &proc) }
return manipulated_value
```

becomes

```
methods.inject(value) { |manipulated_value, (*method, proc)| manipulated_value.public_send(*method, &proc) }
```

Comment: Thank you @Amadan, I have already upvoted your solution as it solves my question elegantly. I'll still wait for few days if somebody comes up with something different, else will accept this answer..